# connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000][1045] Access denied for 'username'@'localhost'(user password:YES) I am trying to connect php and my sql with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
        $servername= "localhost"; 
        $username = "username"; 
        $password = "password"; 
        try { 
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=testing",$username, $password);      
            //set the PDO error mode exception    
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
            echo "connected successfully";
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo " connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if:

- user with username `username` really exists. With default Mysql instalation the standard username is `root`, not `username`.
- the user with `username` has the password `password`. In default MYsql installation the user `root` has no password set.

Comment: By changing username to root and blank passwird, its same error

Answer (score 0):

Check via commandline whether you can connect to your database:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html

> mysql --host=localhost --user=myname --password=password mydb

I believe you are not knowing your credentials to access the database... How did you install the MySQL database?

Comment: I am beginner in it.I am using phpmyadmin

Comment: There is localhost:13306 in phpmyadmin and localhost:13308 in mysqlworkbench.would that affect?if that does how can i change workbwnch 13306 to 13308?